# Save Pyplot 'Hist' to File

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm writing several different plots to disk with pyplot. Most of these are `scatter` plots; `hist` is specifically resisting the approach that works elsewhere.

```
ind_list=range(175,185)
plt_fail_rate1=plt.scatter(ind_list,perf_fail_rate1)
plt.title('Proportion of Failed (size>1 and all unique) Clusters')
plt_fail_rate1.figure.savefig(paath+'/fail_rate1.png')
plt.clf()
```

This approach works for all scatterplots. Below is the analog for histograms which does not work. Note that the problem is with `savefig` specifically - if I replace that line with `plt.show()`, a normal histogram appears in the GUI

```
distr_tmp=tf.opc_size_distr() # get a list from a class
plt_opc_size=plt.hist(distr_tmp)
plt.title('Number of Codes Per Cluster')
#plt.show()
#plt_opc_size.savefig(paath+'/size_distr.png')
#plt_opc_size.figure.savefig(paath+'/size_distr.png')
plt.clf()
```

If I use `.figure.savefig()`, I get `tuple object has no attribute figure`.

If I use `.savefig()`, I get `tuple object has no attribute savefig`. Also, in response to a comment, I tried `.figure().savefig()` and that doesn't work either.

I've used a python shell session to figure to verify the hist-specific problem. Namely, if you store `plt.scatter()` in some variable, you can then call `.figure.savefig()` on that variable with no problem. So, the problem can so summarized as follows:

```
ind_list=[1,2,3]
data_list=[10,-5,-15]
x=plt.scatter(ind_list,data_list)
x.figure.savefig('test.png') # works fine on my laptop
hist_list=[1925,1970]
x=plt.hist(hist_list)
#plt.show() # shows a valid if sparse histogram in a new window
x.figure.savefig('test2.png') #all permutations fail
```

Note that if you're testing this from a shell, you need to be careful (call `plt.clf()` I believe) after you call `show()`, otherwise even the proper call will fail due to `can't invoke 'wm' command` error.

Comment: Where you able to show the figure? using the `show()` function?

Comment: yeah, `show()` works totally fine

Comment: Have you tried `plt_fail_rate1.figure().savefig(paath+'/fail_rate1.png')` ?

Comment: Can you post some sample data from `distr_tmp`

Comment: yes, i've tried `.figure()`. I've also posted a reproducible example (the data I'm plotting takes a while to generate, so plotting 2 points isn't 100% artificial)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that [`plt.hist()` returns a tuple containing 3 elements](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html?highlight=hist#matplotlib.pyplot.hist):

> n : array or list of arrays
>
> The values of the histogram bins. See normed or density and weights
>   for a description of the possible semantics. If input x is an array,
>   then this is an array of length nbins. If input is a sequence arrays
>   [data1, data2,..], then this is a list of arrays with the values of
>   the histograms for each of the arrays in the same order.
>
> bins : array
>
> The edges of the bins. Length nbins + 1 (nbins left edges and right
>   edge of last bin). Always a single array even when multiple data sets
>   are passed in.
>
> patches : list or list of lists
>
> Silent list of individual patches used to create the histogram or list
>   of such list if multiple input datasets.

Only the last one (patches) is a list of `Artist` objects which contain a reference to your figure.

For your code to work, you'd therefore have to do something like:

```
plt_opc_size[2][0].figure.savefig(paath+'/size_distr.png')
```

The `[2]` accesses the 3rd element of the tuple (the list of patches) and `[0]` the first `Artist` in that list.

However, this is not the most elegant way to write your code. You can obtain a reference to your `Figure` using `plt.gcf()`. The following would therefore work in all cases:

```
distr_tmp=tf.opc_size_distr() # get a list from a class
plt_opc_size=plt.hist(distr_tmp)
plt.title('Number of Codes Per Cluster')
plt.gcf().savefig(paath+'/size_distr.png')
plt.clf()
```